# Google Chrome - chrome.runtime in content script increasing memory heap

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, memory-leaks, profiling

I have an extension that loads a content-script which only runs the code `chrome.runtime;`
When i'm creating iframes on-the-fly, wrapped by div, and remove the div after the iframe is loaded,
the memory is not released after running the GC

[image: screenshot]

The first snapshot was taken on page load (after running the garbage-collector)
Then I created and destroyed 150 iframes and took another snapshot

The heap increased in about 900%

- manifest.json:

  ```js
  {
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "ChromeRuntime",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1.0.0",

    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "js": ["load.js"],
        "all_frames": true
      }
    ]
  }
  ```
- load.js:

  ```js
  chrome.runtime;
  ```

If you want to reproduce this on your side:

1. Install extension from 
   https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/yana.bucket/extension.zip
2. Open the main.html from https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/yana.bucket/testPage.zip
3. Run GC
4. Take a heap snapshot
5. Click on "Run!" in the page
6. Run GC
7. Take a heap snapshot

Does someone have any workaround to resolve this issue?

Test page, test.html:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="mainScript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header-row">
            <span onclick="runMe()">Run!</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Test page, mainScript.js:

```js
var tabCount = 0;

function runMe() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
        addNewTab();
    }

    setTimeout(clear, 3000);
}

function addNewTab() {
    var nextTabId = ++tabCount;
    var iframeElm = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframeElm.src = 'iframe.html?id=' + nextTabId + "&isOdd=" + (nextTabId % 2);

    document.body.appendChild(iframeElm);
}

function clear() {
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'),0).forEach(function (iframeElm) {
        document.body.removeChild(iframeElm);
    });
}
```

Test page, iframe.html:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="this-is-iframe">
            This is the IFRAME!
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>The Id is : </span>
            <span id="iframe-id"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>To simulate SPA inside the iframe, press here:</span> <!-- <button onclick='simulateSpa()'>Simulate!</button> -->
        </div>
        <div id='content1'> Some content...</div>
        <div id='content2'>
            <div id='sub-content2'> <span>Sub content</span> <span>Sub content2 </span>  <span>Sub content 3</span> </div>
            <div id='sub-content3'> <span>Sub content</span> <span>Sub content2 </span>  <span>Sub content 3</span> </div>
        </div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like the classic self-induced memory leak due to variable scope capturing in `iframe.onload` closure because removing from DOM doesn't remove `divIframe` reference and it persists forever.

Comment: it also happen while working with iframe directly, with the following code
`function addNewTab() {
 var nextTabId = ++tabCount;
 var iframeElm = document.createElement("iframe");
 iframeElm.src = 'iframe.html?id=' + nextTabId + "&isOdd=" + (nextTabId % 2);

 iframeElm.onload = (function (iframeElm) {
  return function() {
   setTimeout(function() { iframeElm.parentNode.removeChild(iframeElm); }, 3000);
  };
 })(iframeElm);

 document.body.appendChild(iframeElm);
}`

Comment: is there a way to destroy this content-script, or any alternative not to cause a memory leaked?

Comment: hi, and thank you for your response, i tried to run the following code without the extension at all) [https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/yana.bucket/mainScript.js](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/yana.bucket/mainScript.js), and i still got a memory leaked [https://screencast.com/t/TCfrzSr2](http://screencast.com/t/TCfrzSr2), why are we still seeing increase in the memory?

Comment: Now you got me. I don't know. Maybe it's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: just opened a bug for them [https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=647159](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=647159)